# Регулярное выражение для проверки ввода данных поля input атрибутом pattern

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, input

Необходимо реализовать проверку вводимых данных  **password HTML input** с помощью регулярного выражения в атрибуте **pаttern**

**Требования к вводимым данным:**

- пароль должен состоять минимум из 6 символов
- пароль должен содержать минимум 2 английские буквы
- пароль должен содержать минимум 4 цифры

**На данный момент у меня условие от 6 до 15 символов:**

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,15}"
```

Подскажите, как переделать регулярку под нужные требования!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})^.{6,}$"
```

`(?=...)` - позитивный просмотр вперед
`(?:.*[A-Za-z]){2}` группа без захвата, в которой проверяем любое количество символов за которыми следует любая буква в латинского алфавита, квантификатор указывает что таких совпадений должно быть 2.
`(?:.*[0-9]){4}` - группа без захвата, по аналогии с алфавитной
`.{6,}` - 6 и более любых символов, в т.ч. пробельных

---

*С html не знаком, но вроде количество символов можно так же ограничить самим полем, а не регулярным выражением.*
*Type специально поставил text, что бы видеть вводимые данные*

---

Пример работы:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" pattern="(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})^.{6,}$" title="Пароль должен содержать минимум 2 буквы и 4 цифры">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```